# Read blob stored as .h5 and load keras model in Azure Functions in Python

Tags: azure, keras, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to load multiple Keras models or weights into a deployed Azure Function. The blobs are saved in .h5 format. I've accessed the container and a specific blob like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
blob = blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(CONTAINER_NAME,BLOB_NAME)

myBlob = blob.content
```

This returns a byte-object, which Keras' load_model method can't use:

```
from keras.models import load_model
load_model(myBlob)

>>> ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path
```

Is there a way to read the blob as .h5 and not bytes? Or a way to read the bytes-object in a way that is interpretable by Keras?

Comment: Have you tried `get_blob_to_text`?

Comment: Yes, using get_blob_to_text also raised an error. I did however find some sort of workaround for my issue, where I saved the weights as pickle files as bytes and uploaded them to the container:

    weights = model.get_weights()

    fpkl= open('path_name.pkl', 'wb')     
    pickle.dump(weights, fpkl, protocol= pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    fpkl.close()

And loaded them up with dill.loads(blob.content) in the Azure Function.

Comment: As the [document](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/#load_model-function) of keras model shows, `load_model` needs filepath of the .hd5 file. You could use `get_blob_to_path` to get the filepath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import h5py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
from io import BytesIO
con_str = ''
blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(con_str, 'test', 'model.h5')
downloader = blob_client.download_blob(0)

with BytesIO() as f:
    downloader.readinto(f)
    with h5py.File(f, 'r') as h5file:
        model = load_model(h5file)
        model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!